# https keep-alive?

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, keep-alive, response-headers

I know how to do it for http, and it's [pretty easy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

But how do you do it for https in iis?

If the method linked above is supposed to do it for https, it doesn't work on mine, or at least I receive no `keep-alive` response headers.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTTP 1.1, keep-alive is assumed as default, according to RFC2616 - even for HTTPS connections.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1